# json-schema-validator required JDK version does it support Java 6

Tags: java, json, java-6, json-schema-validator

There is no clear documentation about supported JDK version (or I didn't find it). Only found a [change log](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator/wiki/ChangeLog_22x) for version 2.2.3 mentioned Java 1.6.

Comment: What you posted sounds like a statement. Do you have a question? What exactly are you doing, and are you getting an error message? What is the exact error message?

Comment: The question is in title, does it support Java 6? I'm evaluating optional libs according to official docs, not in the phase integrate into my project. You have any experience in using this lib?

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ryuukei recording to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html even java 7 was dedicated in April 2015, use JDK 8 instead

Comment: hey, thanks guys. :-) But customer requirement matters the most. Thus we have to support JDK 6 in the project, that's why I'm evaluating which lib is the best option.